# Directive with transclude 'element', thorws an error when applied on select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I try to create directive which simply copies transcluded content. 
The only constraint is that I would like to use `transclude: 'element'` option. Directive has following structure:

```
angular.module('app').directive('mySelect', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    transclude: 'element',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
      transclude(scope, function(clone) {
        el.after(clone);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

However, when I try to use it in the following scenario:

```
<select my-select ng-model="myCountry" 
        ng-options="country.isoCode as country.name for country in countries"> 
</select>
```

I get an error: `Error: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.`

All variables are properly scoped, how can I solve this issue?

[Plunker Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mBmEawgWexlMsWFzXHPt?p=preview)